# 100% Div height with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, height, css

I'm having some trouble setting my Div to 100% of the window and would love some help figuring this out.

Here is the abbreviated html...

```
<div id="full-slider-wrapper">
  <div id="full-slider">
    <div class="slide-panel active">
       CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
/*SLIDER
===================================
*/

#full-slider-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#full-slider {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#full-slider .slide-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#full-slider .slide-panel.active {
    visibility: visible;
     }
```

I've been using min-height: 1250px; as a workaround, but I'm using the SKELETON theme and when I resize the window, the content shrinks and I'm left with a large amount of empty space between the content and footer.

I know there have been a lot of similar questions asked, but I can't seem to get any of the solutions to work. It seems like my best option is to utilize some jQuery like below:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('div:full-slider').height($(window).height() - $('div:full-slider').offset().top);
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Unfortunately I'm not very proficient with jQuery and whenever I try to implement the above or something similar, my content disappears.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `html, body, #full-slider-wrapper, #full-slider { height:100% }`

Answer (score 2):

Percentage heights will not work unless all parents (ancestors) have defined height, so add:

```
html, body, #full-slider-wrapper, #full-slider { height:100%; }
```

Also add `height:100%` to all other ancestors of `#full-slider-wrapper` if any.

Of course, if you have a footer you will have to balance the heights to make up space for the footer e.g. `#full-slider-wrapper { height:90%; }`.

Comment: I tried this, but the content doesn't appear. I've just got my header and footer.

Comment: Provide a fiddle to demonstrate the issue please, it is hard to debug your page otherwise. It should work fine provided you've set a defined height on all elements that have children with % height.

Answer (score 2):

Situations like this are great to make everything position absolute, but name all four positions. Example:

```
#full-slider {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

This particular one will force $full-slider to the edges of its parent, but the logic applies for everything. Want footer height of 50px? Do bottom:50px. Change as needed.

Comment: I'm able to adjust 'Top' to account for my header, but adjusting 'Bottom' has no impact on my footer placement relative to the content. The footer is stuck in the middle of the page and the content runs over it.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$('element').css('height','100vh');
```

or this:

```
.element_class{
   height:100vh;
}
```